# RSA: same symbols in plaintext give same symbols ciphertext?

Tags: cryptography, rsa, asymmetric, programming

I just started studying Information Security, but I just ran this program:

http://www.sanfoundry.com/cpp-program-implement-rsa-algorithm/

and faced this strange thing. For small keys (don't try to run it for huge primes, it doesn't give good output), like 211 and 223, inputting a string like `1122` gives output of type `aabb`, because first two symbols are the same and last two symbols as well. Is it how RSA works? I was pretty sure it mixes the bits up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Single, unpadded input chars**
That implementation you linked operates on individual characters. So patterns are repeated.

Also these characters are not padded in any way. Padding would prevent such easily spotted patterns.

**Not the real thing**
So this is somewhat RSA like. But it is not actual RSA. (Because PKCS#1 mandates padding.) Wikipedia calls this "Plain RSA". Another name heard here is "Textbook RSA".

**Further reading**

- See section "Trading secrets" here: [The First Few Milliseconds of an HTTPS Connection](http://www.moserware.com/2009/06/first-few-milliseconds-of-https.html)
- See section "Padding" here: Wikipedia: [RSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(algorithm))

Comment: Thank you, cannot upvote though, too little reputation.

Comment: Or "raw RSA". Raw RSA is just modular exponentiation, it's not secure at all, there are at least 10 attacks or so. That it is fully deterministic - i.e. always encrypts to the same value - is just one.

Comment: @JamesPond You can accept though (grey mark next to the answer). If you are not sure you can wait a while before doing so.